# does Android market validate app versions not yet released?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm trying to implement a beta testing program before releasing my apps but unfortunately users are reporting they cannot validate their license.
I can validate using the market developer dashboard, without issues.
Does the Android market allow validation of app versions yet to be officially released ?

Thanks

---

.I released the app and the users are still complaining they can't validate the license so the analysis isn't conclusive.
On the  other hand I've been asking myself which would be the reasons for an app to answer in different ways for real 
users and test accounts.why? Because I added the email account of one of those user that couldn't validate  to my test accounts list and it worked!
I´ve confirmed the users have bought the app and market has validated 
their licenses before. 
Things I´m thinking of: 
- I´ve changed my development environment recently. After changing my 
notebook I´ve had issues signing my apks: went back from JRE 7 to JRE 
6 and everything seemed fined. 
- Any reasons why Android Market should stop validating users after 
updating from one version to another? I´ve double checked 
LICENSE_OLD_KEY using test accounts and it is working as expected. 
- which changes could make Android market stop understanding that the app published is the same app users paid for?
- Will I need to create a new user, attach someone else's credit card 
and download my own app so I can debug market answers? 
Please, help! 
Thanks, 
Gabriel Simões

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using LVL??

The app needs to be purchased before the license can be validated. Alternatively you can add the gmail accounts of your users as test users here: https://market.android.com/publish/Home#ProfileEditorPlace:

Comment: Yes I'm using lvl.my main issue is that w while the coffee works for me when using the developer dashboard authorization users are complaining the app is not validating as expected.

Comment: I need to know if lvl would validate a new version of my app not yet released on market but used by users who bought the license before (i authorize license_old)

Comment: As far as I know LVL does not care about the version. It validates only on the package name.

Comment: Since i can't but my own apps and my credit card is associated to my account i can't download and test my own apps...

Comment: test accounts are set up at the link i gave in my original answer

Comment: This is what i know and what i have relayed to be working.the problem occurs only with users that paid for the app...in this new version they aren't able to validate their licenses...although i can using test accounts

Comment: This may be an issue in your implementation. Obviously the limited information we have here does not allow us to diagnose the issue but if you are sure you have implemented everything correctly you could possibly raise an issue with Google Support. First though you should check the status that LVL is returning to your app and make sure you are handling it correctly.

Comment: Guys, sorry if I didn´t make myself clear. Everything is working justr as expected if I use any test accounts. The problem is that users are complaining they can´t validate even when connected to the internet, but I can if I use my test account. Shouldn´t the answers be the same for everybody? Do they change in those 2 scenarios?